# Creating channel and setChannel troubles

Tags: discord.js

I'm having trouble creating a discord bot, what it should do is detect whenever someone jkoins a specific voice Chat, and if a user does, the bot would have to create a new channel with, as the name, the nickname of the user who joined, then move that user to the new created channel and set that channel to private so no one can join.

Currently my problems are:
-I can't set the name of the new channel as the nickname of the user
-I can't move the user to that channel
-And I think the rest may work

Here is the part of my code:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(newMember.channelID != '693086073244483614') return;

    const nick = newMember.nickname;
    newMember.guild.channels.create('test', { type: 'voice' })
    .then(() => {
        newMember.setChannel('test');
        console.log(`Hello from ${newMember.channel}!`);
        const nChannel = newMember.channel;
        nChannel.setParent('690292158636360032');
        nChannel.overwritePermissions([
            {
                parent: '#690292158636360032',
                id: '532236212967047169',
                deny: ['CONNECT'],
            },
        ]);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appriciated, I'm new to both discord bots and javascript, so thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Client#voiceStateUpdate` event does not return a member, it returns a VoiceState. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate

From the VoiceState, you can get a member with `<VoiceState>.member`.

So to fix your error, replace `const nick = newMember.nickname` to `const nick = newMember.member.nickname`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  var oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel;
  var newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel;
  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) { //User joined the channel.
    if(newMember.voiceChannel.id != '693086073244483614') return; //Check if the user join the right voice channel.

    let nick = newMember.nickname;
    if(nick == null){
      nick = newMember.user.username; //If the member doesn't have a nickname.
    }
    newMember.guild.createChannel(nick, { type: 'voice' })
    .then((nChannel) => {
        console.log(`Hello from ${nChannel}!`);
        nChannel.setParent('690292158636360032'); //Your category ID
        nChannel.overwritePermissions(nChannel.guild.defaultRole.id, {
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false
        });
        newMember.setVoiceChannel(nChannel)
    });

  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){ //User left the channel.
    if(oldMember.voiceChannel.parent == null) return;
    if(oldMember.voiceChannel.parent.id != '690292158636360032') return; //Check if the voice channel is under the specified category.
    if(oldMember.voiceChannel.members.first() == null){ //There is no more users in this channel.
      oldMember.voiceChannel.delete(); //Delete the channel.
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the final result, fully working. I also add a system to automatically remove the channel if there is nobody in.
I have added some annotations, tell me if you have any questions.

Comment: nickname will be undefined, not null.  It's best to just check if it's falsy ``if(!nick) {}``.  Alternatively, Member.displayName does all this for you.  It will be the nickname if available or the user name.

Comment: Thank you so much dude fir your help. It says though that newUserChannel is undefined? Are you sure you used discord.js v 12?

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but it seems to not work still.

Comment: I have tried it, it's fully working. Make sure to have the latest discord.js version.

Comment: See @yogurtsyum's answer. You're using the event incorrectly for v12.